# Fault-tolerance with Payara4/Hazelcast x failure in first instance

Tags: hazelcast, payara

I followed the tutorial https://blog.payara.fish/payara-server-basics-creating-a-simple-cluster.

Then, I understood that all configs I made in instance1 are mirrored to others.

But, if the instance1 fails, what happens? Does all instances stop to work?

Is there some way to allow a better fault-tolerance for this?

And, if the instance1 stops forever, because for example a fault in hard-drive, and I need to reformat the OS/install all softwares again, do I need to recreate all the other instances again?